# Budgie application menu applet scroll problem

Tags: kali-linux, scrolling, panel, budgie

[image]

I am new to Linux. I am using the Kali-Linux with budgie desktop environment. In this environment, if I click on the application menu applet, it doesn't show the top part of the menu. If i move the panel to the bottom then the bottom part can't be seen. And I can't even scroll up or down.

How can I fix this issue? Or can I install any other panel in this desktop environment?